# Want to avoid spacing between each stacked bars in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am working with Highcharts and have come across a little problem that I am struggling to overcome.

I have created a jsfiddle so you can see my issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/jo_pappi/0e5h8sts/3/ [A]

As you can see

[image: Needed Output format]

I can achieve the above format in highcharts, Since this chart is rendering based on dynamic data When a single group values arrives highcharts leaves so much space between the bars. Am attaching image here

And the code

```
$('#container-one').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        events: {
            click: function (event) {
                console.log(event.pageX + ',' + event.pageY);
            }
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
        minPadding: 1.1,
        maxPadding: 1.1
    },

    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of fruits'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        // column: {
        //     stacking: 'normal'
        // }
        series: {
            pointWidth: 20,
            stacking: 'normal',
            borderWidth: 0,
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    //reloadFlash();
                    //$('#report').html('click on yAxis title');
                    console.log(event.pageX + ',' + event.pageY);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        color: 'rgba(89,89,89,1)',
        data: [5],                     // data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 4],
        stack: 'male',
        pointPadding: -0.0,
        pointPlacement: -0.0
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        color: 'rgba(255,95,215,1)',
        data: [3],                    // data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 2],
        stack: 'male',
        pointPadding: -0.0,
        pointPlacement: -0.0
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        color: 'rgba(217,116,0,1)',
        data: [2],                    // data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
        stack: 'female',
        pointPadding: -0.0,
        pointPlacement: -0.0
    }, {
        name: 'Janet',
        color: 'rgba(155,215,255,1)',
        data: [3],        // data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
        stack: 'female',
        pointPadding: -0.0,
        pointPlacement: -0.0
    }]

});
```

[image: Image shows the problem]

how can i reduce the spaces between bars?

If changing **height** of the chart is one solution means how can i achieve this dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing **"pointWidth"** solved the white space between the bars. But i need the bars should be off same height in all possible cases. I have solved the problem by setting height dynamically based on the categories count. say for example if am having *only one category i have set the height for the chart as "210" and for 2 categories "270" like that*. and removed pointWidth.

```
$('#container-one').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 210,
        ...
        .
        .
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: {
            //pointWidth: 20,
            stacking: 'normal',
        .
        .
});
```

When i have two categories i have set chart height as **270**

```
$('#container-two').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 270,
        ...
        .
        .
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: {
            //pointWidth: 20,
            stacking: 'normal',
        .
        .
});
```

and the [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jo_pappi/0e5h8sts/)

may be what i did was wrong. But its fixed my problem. correct me if am wrong.

Thanks all

Comment: Is there the best way to do this? What if I have more than 8 categories then it would not nice practice to write like this. Can anybody have a better solution for this?

Comment: @RAVIPATEL It's been years since I worked on this, hoping that by this time the Library should have fixed this issue maybe check on that.

Comment: No. Library hasn't fixed this issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using  **'pointWidth: 20'** in series for ?? That is creating the problem.. Also you are giving the  **categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']** even if the data comes for only apples.. one solution would be to generate the categories dynamically.. say for example if data comes only for apples push only apples in the categories array. Then after that you can use :

```
 _chart.setSize(width,height)
```

method to dynamically set the new height and width of the highchart. Also removing **pointWidth** will solve the problem ...

Comment: Indeed, problem comes from `pointWidth` - when disabled, works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/0e5h8sts/7/

Comment: Thanks for the responses folks. removing **"pointWidth"** solved the white space between the bars. but i need the bars should be off same height in all possible cases. I have solved the problem by setting height dynamically based on the categories count. say for example if am having only one category i have set the height for the chart as "210" and for 2 categories "270" like that. and removed **pointWidth**. Will add answer with fiddle link below

Answer (score 1):

The options you can use are:

```
plotOptions:{
    bar:{
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0,
    }
}
```

But you also need to not force your bar point width.

Remove:

```
series: {
            pointWidth: 20,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d9f8b22x/

The API docs discuss how these options relate to each other:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPadding

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SteveP. Have removed the pointWidth and used padding to avoid the space between bars. to maintain the bar width i have set height of the chart dynamically for different no of categories which is also am getting dynamically from the server. here is the test fiddle link [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jo_pappi/0e5h8sts/)